# mutate conditional on row elements matching within group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data set with unique location ID's (`loc_id`) across years. But some of the locations are coded differently. Note that for `loc_id` 1 , the `location` is coded as "mall" for 2017, but it is coded as "financial institution" for the rest of the years.

```
data <- tribble(
  ~year, ~location, ~loc_id,
  "2017","mall",1,
  "2018","financial institution",1,
  "2019","financial institution",1,
  "2020","financial institution", 1)
```

I need to create two new variables. The first variable looks at whether ANY row in the `location` col contains the the string "financial institution", and if it does, the variable is called "financial institution". This variable is `location_clean`.

The second variable looks at the `location` variable and checks whether there is any difference in the location string, and if there is a difference, we create a "yes/no" binary variable. This variable is called `location_same`.

I attached an example of what the final data set should look like.

```
data <- tribble(
  ~year, ~location, ~loc_id, ~location_clean, ~location_same,
  "2015","mall", 1, "financial institution", "no",
  "2016","mall", 1, "financial institution", "no",
  "2017","mall", 1, "financial institution", "no",
  "2018","financial institution", 1, "financial institution", "no",
  "2019","financial institution", 1, "financial institution", "no",
  "2020","financial institution", 1, "financial institution", "no")
```

I need to do these steps group across `loc_id` because there are many locations in the actual dataset.

thanks,

Comment: what your location_clean has to be if 'financial institution' is not there in a loc_id group?

Comment: oh good question. If "'financial institution" isn't in a loc_id, then the location clean should be whatever is in the location column, irrespective of whatever it different across years.

Comment: yes, I've mentioned same in my answer, can you please check if that works for you?

Comment: I just checked. The first part of the code is OK and the location_clean variable is correctly coded. But the the location_same variable is coding everything as "no" even when they are not different.

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: Great, if it did, could you please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(loc_id) %>% 
   mutate(location_clean = case_when('financial institution' %in% location ~ 'financial institution', TRUE ~ location),
          location_same = case_when(length(unique(location)) != 1 ~ 'no', TRUE ~ 'yes'))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   loc_id [1]
  year  location              loc_id location_clean        location_same
  <chr> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>        
1 2017  mall                       1 financial institution no           
2 2018  financial institution      1 financial institution no           
3 2019  financial institution      1 financial institution no           
4 2020  financial institution      1 financial institution no
```